# How to turn on Location in lollipop or up version and get current location

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location, android-gps

I try to turn on gps location in lollipop device(not emulator).I wrote real time permission code,but not working correct.This is my source:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        askForGPS();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void askForGPS(){
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(client, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, GPS_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In button click i try to ask permission like this.

```
askForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,LOCATION);
```

When i run my app ,i can't show alertDialog and can't turn on location .I don't know but program showing this Toast message "is already granted."
My askForPermission method not working correct.My question is that how i can turn on GPS with real time permission and get current location?

```
 public void getCurrenctLocation(Location location)
{
    Log.e("Current lang", location.getLatitude()+"");
    Log.e("Current long", location.getLongitude()+"");
}
```

How and where i can use my getCurrenctLocation method?
thank

Answer (score 0):

1) Modify your `askForPermission()` like this:

```
private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

    } else {
           askForGPS();
    }
}
```

2) Modify `onRequePermissionResult()` like below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
     switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION:            //You have to declare LOCATION globally. example: private int LOCATION = 1 ;

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                askForGPS();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }            
            else {
                 if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permissions[0])) {
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied permanently, please go to app settings to grant permission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                  }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your attention .How i can use getCurrenctLocation method to check current location after gps has turn on? @tahsinRupam

Comment: you can get location by using getLastLocation/location change listener

Comment: can you tell me what is permission in onRequestPermissionsResult @tahsinRupam

Comment: The permission you request in a string, (ex: Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)